# c# Buffer conflict on concurrent TCP clients in BeginReceive

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, asyncsocket

i wrote a TCP server (Async Socket method in c# language) that can be get username and password from the clients, when one client connect and supply username and password everything will be work correctly and next users can store their username and password in a list, but when one client connect and then second client connect concurrently the second connected user's password take the place but with correct digit number of first client password;

```
the sequence events of environment

client1 connect;
client2 connect;

client1 enter username; (for example JOHN)
client2 enter username;(for example  JACK)
client2 enter password;(for example 123456)
client1 enter password;(for example abc)

in the list is see;
 list{
    [0]:
         username : JOHN
         password : 123
    [1] 
         username : JACK
         password : 123456
}
```

as you see in above the first connected password is in correct size but with secondly connected clients password (which enter password earlier)
my codes is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MyTestServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public  byte[] _buffer;
        public byte[] _PASSBUFF;
        private static Socket _ServerSocket = new Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        private  List<SpecificClient> _ClientDirectory = new List<SpecificClient>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            Program SS = new Program();
            SS.SetupServer();
            //SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        private  void SetupServer()
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting up server ...");
                _ServerSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 100));
                _ServerSocket.Listen(5);
                _ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), _ServerSocket);    
        }
        private  void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {

            Socket socket = _ServerSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            _ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), _ServerSocket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            string RequestForUsername = "Enter your username: ";
            byte[] RFU_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(RequestForUsername);
            socket.BeginSend(RFU_byte, 0, RFU_byte.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onCompleteRequestForUsername), socket);

        }

        private  void onCompleteRequestForUsername(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
            _buffer = new byte[1024];
            socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onUsernameReceived), socket);

        }



        private  void onUsernameReceived(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
                Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
                int RcvFromClient = socket.EndReceive(AR);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[RcvFromClient];
                Array.Copy(_buffer, buffer, buffer.Length);
                string RcvUsername = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                SpecificClient NewUser = new SpecificClient();
                NewUser._username = RcvUsername;
                NewUser._UserSocket = socket;
                _ClientDirectory.Add(NewUser);

                buffer = new byte[1024];
                buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\nEnter your password: ");
                socket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onSendPropmtForPass), socket);



        }
        private void onSendPropmtForPass(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
            _PASSBUFF = new byte[1024];
            socket.BeginReceive(_PASSBUFF, 0, _PASSBUFF.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(onReceivePassword), socket);
        }

        private void onReceivePassword(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            int ByteCountRcvPass = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] PassBuff = new byte[ByteCountRcvPass];
            Array.Copy(_PASSBUFF, PassBuff, PassBuff.Length);
            string RcvPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(PassBuff);

            foreach ( SpecificClient Wanted in _ClientDirectory)
            {
                if (Wanted._UserSocket == socket)
                {
                    Wanted._password = RcvPassword;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are connections sharing a buffer?

Comment: So how can i assign different buffer to different users ?
i define buffer in global for accessing it inside the static methods and callbacks.

Comment: Pass a custom class in to the begin method instead of `socket`. that class can hold the socket and buffer

Comment: Could you write a piece of your code for better understanding ?

Comment: [**Classes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)